# java file handling on ubuntu

Tags: java, file, samba

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04. My machine is  connected to remote server, for example `smb://192.168.10.41/data/Oct2014/info.txt`.

I am writing the code to check whether specific file exists on this server or not, even if file is there it is giving output as `false`. My code:

```
System.out.println(new File("smb://192.168.10.41/data/Oct2014/info.txt").exists());
```

Comment: This obviously won't work. `File` can only query local filesystem paths. Try and mount the server endpoint instead. Or use JCFIS.

Comment: but my server is already mounted on my local machine.

Comment: If you have mounted the server then you should have an absolute path to it.

Comment: @Yogesh Something like `/media/server/data/Oct2014/info.txt`

Comment: yes the absolute path is exactly same as i have give in SOP statement in my problem.

Comment: Thats not an absolute path, it's a URL, but you need to use the local path. Can you confirm where the samba share is mounted - the exact path. i.e. /media/????. Then you should be able to use the code as follows:
`System.out.println(new File("<PATH_STATED_ABOVE>/data/Oct2014/info.txt").exists());`